# Cannot find module 'nx/src/config/workspaces' on creating a React app on existing Nx project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, hadoop-yarn, nomachine-nx

I am getting the following error and I add the react app to the already existing Nx project on my system:

```
Require stack:
- C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\amagi-qtc\node_modules\@nrwl\devkit\index.js
- C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\amagi-qtc\node_modules\@nrwl\react\src\utils\lint.js
- C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\amagi-qtc\node_modules\@nrwl\react\src\generators\application\application.js
- C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\amagi-qtc\node_modules\nx\src\shared\workspace.js
- C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\amagi-qtc\node_modules\nx\src\cli\init-local.js
- C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\amagi-qtc\node_modules\nx\bin\nx.js
- C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@nrwl\cli\node_modules\nx\bin\nx.js
- C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@nrwl\cli\bin\nx.js
```

I did to install react in a nx project

```
yarn add -D @nrwl/react
```

But when I run this command:

```
nx g @nrwl/react:app my-new-app
```

It gives me the above error.

Answer (score 17):

The issue could have happened due to the project not having the latest NX version packages.

Ensure the nx cli is installed in your local project, `yarn add -D @nrwl/cli`.

Run `nx migrate latest` from your project to do the upgrades, it will update your package.json file.

You can review the changes made to package.json and run `yarn` to install them.

Finally, you have to run the migrations by running `nx migrate --run-migrations`.

Reference: https://nx.dev/using-nx/updating-nx#updating-nx

Answer (score 4):

If anyone stumbles upon this in 2023 and beyond here's the simple solution which worked for me.

- Remove `node_modules` in entirety - `rm -rf node_modules`
- Delete package-lock file. Sometimes nx can update few entries here which can cause issues when the app is started.
- Once you rerun `npm install`, ensure you install the nx plugin package with the exact version of nx (As per package.json file.- `npm install @nrwl/nx-plugin@<Exact version number>`

Comment: with nx version: 16.6.0, I did remove, reinstall node_modules, and delete package-lock.json, but no need to install the nx-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The real solution is,

1. Identify the Nx version you want to use, say v13.
2. Install it locally via `npm install --save-dev nx@13`